# "Obsequy" as a more concise synonym of "sycophancy"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, synonyms

Yesterday I was composing some text and found myself in need of a concise, formal word denoting an act or practice of servile, insincere flattery. As I mentally searched for the right word, the semantically-related words *sycophant* and *obsequious* came to mind, but neither was quite right for the job: *sycophant* denotes the actor rather than the action, and *obsequious* is an adjective rather than a noun. From *sycophant* I considered *sycophancy*, but that word just seemed too long and arcane. From *obsequious* I considered *obsequiousness*, but that word too is excessively long. Then I thought, what about *obsequy*? Wouldn't that be the root word of *obsequious*, just as *calumny* is the root of *calumnious*? Surely no one would describe slander as "calumniousness"!

To my surprise, however, I found that most dictionaries (*e.g.*,
[AHD5](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=obsequy),
[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/obsequy),
[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obsequy),
[RH](http://dictionary.infoplease.com/obsequy))
either don't have an entry for *obsequy*, or have only a redirect to *obsequies*—an obscure word I'd never encountered before, meaning "funeral rites". The few references that did have an entry for non-funereal *obsequy* simply defined it as "obsequiousness".

This surprises me. It seems to me that *obsequy*—meaning an act or practice of servile, insincere flattery—would be a useful word to have in one's arsenal. To what extent **is** it [descriptive!], or **should** it be [prescriptive!], acceptable to use the word in this way?

There are, of course, many other examples of {*-ious* adjective/*-y* noun} pairs; a few are *acrimonious*/*acrimony*, *harmonious*/*harmony*, *parsimonious*/*parsimony*, and *sanctimonious*/*sanctimony*.

(Incidentally, in that moment yesterday, I ended up throwing formality to the winds and chose *ass-kissing*. =)

Comment: Etymology can help: Obsequy (n.):
late 14c., from Old French obseque, osseque "funeral rites," from Medieval Latin obsequiae, influenced in sense by confusion of Latin obsequium "compliance" (see obsequious) with exsequiae "funeral rites." Now usually in plural, obsequies.

Comment: Obsequious (adj.)
late 15c., "prompt to serve," from Middle French obséquieux (15c.), from Latin obsequiosus "compliant, obedient," from obsequium "compliance, dutiful service," from obsequi "to accommodate oneself to the will of another," from ob "after" (see ob-) + sequi "to follow" (see sequel). Pejorative sense of "fawning, sycophantic" had emerged by 1590s. Etymonline

Comment: See, I'd just go with *mocking*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An interesting dilemma!

In [Middle English](https://books.google.com/books?id=rm7HX_ckioEC&pg=PA30&dq=%22obsequy%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=NnfaVPfMCbHIsASFtIHoCA&ved=0CEIQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=%22obsequy%22&f=false), *obsequi* was firmly aligned with *obsequious*:

> obsequi n. (1) also obseque. [L obsequium]
>
> Obedient service; the dutiful performance of a certain duty; also, the
>   attentive service of menials

But it was still used in the singular form to refer to the funeral ritual:

> (a) a service for the dead; funeral

Although *servile insincere flattery* was probably among the *certain duties in the attentive service of menials* in that day, the word is no longer used that way. The vestiges of obsequy are only preserved through the corruption of *exsequiae*: religious rituals. To use *obsequy* as a synonym for *sycophancy* would require turning the clock back quite a few hundred years.

Descriptively, the dilemma is interesting, but it also simple: not today.

Prescriptively, if you start using *obsequy* that way, it might not take a lot of effort to resurrect the old meaning. Words never die; they just sleep.

Answer (score 3):

The OED (Oxford English Dictionary) has ***obsequy***. It is listed twice, the first entry dealing with the meaning concerning funeral rites.

The second entry lists two senses:

a. Ready compliance with the will or pleasure of another, esp. a superior; deferential service; obsequiousness.

b. An act of compliance or deferential service. Freq. in pl.

Several sample extracts are provided for each dating from 1425 to the present time.

It derives from the classical Latin *obsequium* - compliance. A French version *obseque* is dated from 1375.